# Jquery+XML+Google Maps works on FF/IE but no in Chrome/Opera

Tags: jquery, xml, google-maps-api-3

For some days i´m battling with this issue: i´m using Jquery to extract data from a XML and place it on Google Maps V3 as markers, but it doesnt place any marker on Chrome and Opera, after some debugging i found out the problem is in this lines:

```
  var lat = $(this).find("geo\\:lat").text();      
  var lng = $(this).find("geo\\:long").text();
```

In the XML is , i need to remove the ":".

While in FF and IE the "\" to remove ":" works perfectly, on Chrome and Opera doesnt work..but if i go to the XML and remove the ":" from that field and run the code using this lines, it works perfectly.

```
  var lat = $(this).find("geolat").text();      
  var lng = $(this).find("geolong").text();
```

This is a simplified version that replicates the error on Chrome and Opera
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15802004/teste.zip
To replicate the error, this is the comment/uncomment lines.

```
//url: "teste1.xml",     
  url: "teste2.xml",

(and...)        

    //var lat = $(this).find("geo\\:lat").text();            
   //var lng = $(this).find("geo\\:long").text();             
      var lat = $(this).find("geolat").text();      
      var lng = $(this).find("geolong").text();
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: Thanks for answering, but didint work, still working on FF but not in Chrome/Opera. I´m using a PHP function to download the XML to my server, maybe my last hope is to remove ":" from the XML using PHP before calling it in the jQuery. But i really want to resolve this issue without changing the XML, is there other way to remove the ":" in jQuery?

Comment: Thanks for updating. It gives a error:
"$(this).replace is not a function"

Comment: `$(this).find('geo:lat').replaceWith('geolat');
$(this).find('geo:long').replaceWith('geolong');
var lat= $(this).find('geolat').text();
var lng= $(this).find('geolong').text();`

Comment: This error "$(this).replace is not a function" is regarding the last comment from HanhNghien. Somehow stackoverflow added my comment previous the last one. The issue is still not resolved :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known, but still unfixed bug.

You may use `getElementsByTagNameNS()` instead(works in FF,Chrome & Opera) and `$.find()` as a fallback for IE.

Example for `geo:lat`:

```
var lat =(( $.browser.msie )
           ? $(this).find('geo\\:lat')
           : $(this.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#','lat'))
         ).text();
```